# php code not redirecting me to page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `login.php`, `register.php` page.

The `register` page is working fine, but I have a problem with my `login` page.

When I log in successfully, it is supposed to redirect me to a page called `member.php` but instead just stays on the same page and goes no where.

Here is my code for the `login.php` page where I think the problem may be occuring I have tried replacing `header("Location: member.php");` with `echo("Success")` and it works:

Login.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
        <h3>Login Form</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
        </form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];

        $con=mysql_connect('localhost:8889','root','root') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die("cannot select DB");

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($numrows!=0) {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $dbusername=$row['username'];
                $dbpassword=$row['password'];
            }

            if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;
                header("Location: member.php");
            }

        } else {
            echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }

    } else {
        echo "All fields are required!";
    }
}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

member.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])) {
    header("location:login.php");
} else {

?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>! <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h2>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php } ?>
```

Database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyfud.png

[image]

Comment: You can't set a header after any output has been done, move your php code to the top of your `Login.php` file.

Comment: move your script processing to the top of the page and set all errors in a variable array for display within the html, not inline as PHP. As Krister said, you can't set header info after anything has been output to the browser without a cheap workaround.

Comment: thanks you first person to comment and it actually worked thats a first

Comment: Turn on error reporting, it helps a LOT on development. This kind mistake should output a big notification.

Comment: You need output buffering - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't set headers with `header(...)` after any html. You can work around this problem with output buffering. Try adding the following to the top of login.php (that is before your doctype declaration)

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the `header("Location: member.php")` before any other output. So *first* check if the user has to be redirected (and do so if yes) and *then* output everything from `<!doctype html>` on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;
    echo "<script language='javascript'> window.location='member.php'; </script>";
}
```

### member.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'> window.location='login.php'; </script>";
}
```